# making a transparent window as a canvas for drawing

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, annotations, transparent

I've been working on an application in Visual Studio and I've stumbled on a problem for an annotation feature I wish to implement. Basically, I would like to be able to use my mouse to draw on the screen. I checked some other questions here initially and thought to make a transparent window to draw on, but making the window fully transparent caused my mouse clicks to trigger other windows, which won't work.

I then tried to set an extremely low opacity for the window with a white background, which caused the screen to be slightly shaded, which was fine. However, doing this for the whole window caused the line I drew to also have an extremely low opacity and thus remain basically invisible.

Is there a way to solve this problem using the transparent window, or will I have to do something like take a screenshot and make a window-sized picture for the user to draw on? This seems less elegant of a solution and for other features in my application, I would like to avoid this if possible, but if that appears to be the only way, some help in the implementation would be really appreciated.

Thank you!
Kevin

Comment: is this about wpf, winforms, or...?

Comment: ah, sorry, i'm using wpf

Comment: Don't set the Window's Opacity but instead use a Background with low opacity, e.g. #01FFFFFF.

Comment: whoah, that totally works! thank you, I didn't know there were transparent backgrounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the Window's Opacity but instead use a Background with low opacity, e.g. #01FFFFFF:

```
<Window ... Background="#01FFFFFF">
    ...
</Window>
```

Alternatively you could explicitly create a SolidColorBrush as Background and set its Opacity to a small value:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.01"/>
    </Window.Background>
    ...
</Window>
```